# Makefile automatic variables not escaping characters in filenames

Tags: makefile, escaping, automatic-variable

I am using automatic variables with static pattern rules in a Makefile, but I have a problem with filenames with parentheses. The parentheses are not escaped properly for the shell, and I get a syntax error from the shell:

```
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

Is there a way to get `make` to automatically escape "bad" characters in filenames? I have tried using parentheses, such as `$(<)` and `$(@)`, but it does not seem to make a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you just put some single quotes around the automatic variables when you're passing them to the shell? So, instead of `$<`, try `'$<'`.  If you have to do this with something that equates to more than a single filename, e.g. `$+` then you could use `$(patsubst %,'%',$+)`